# JFreechart. Axis labels inside a plot

Tags: java, jfreechart, label

Is there any way to draw JFreeChart graph with axis labels placed inside a plot? I'm writing an app with many chart panels in a single screen, labels oriented inside a plot will greatly improve useful space of panels.

Comment: Maybe one of the [Combined Axis Charts](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) shown in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp)?

Comment: Additionally you can set negative label insets.